# Cloudwatch Log event aggregation pattern?

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a series of webservices and platform applications whose logs contain data about events pertinent to disparate parts of the overall platform. All of these logs are logged to Cloudwatch and my company is exclusively an AWS shop for new applications.

I would like to aggregate these log events in some sort of data store I can use to gain insights across the platform and conduct some predictive analytics based on the event data.

**What would be my best options for designing this?** My initial thought would be to Firehose the data into a Dynamo table but I would love some input from those more familiar with this type of problem.

Comment: This is a really broad question, and a good answer will depend on how you've formatted your log messages, how much effort you want to put into parsing them, and the sorts of analyses that you want to do.

Comment: In general, however, I think you'll be happier writing the messages into Elasticsearch rather than Dynamo: the former is designed for searching, while the latter does it under duress (and requiring high read capacity units). You'll probably want to do some parsing and preprocessing before loading the data into ES (or wherever). Assuming that you're planning to use a CloudWatch Logs subscription, Lambda is the logical tool to use for this preprocessing.

Comment: You might also be interested in [this article](https://www.kdgregory.com/index.php?page=aws.loggingPipeline) that I wrote. It's somewhat Java-centric (and uses a Log4J appender library that I wrote), but the basic pipeline is applicable to any language, as is the idea that log messages should be written in JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the info kdgregory

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Did you try CW Log Insight ?

Then, I believe you are much better off streaming your CW logs to ElasticSearch. There is [native support for it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_ES_Stream.html) and as ES is a pretty standard platform for log-analytics, chances are you will get better community support and better tool. Really save you the headaches you can get into trying to implement something new for DynamoDB